# w-2 form shows two different localities and values for wages and local income tax withheld

Tags: united-states, taxes, ohio

I live in Akron but work at Lakemore, Ohio. I do understand taxes not being withheld for Akron. But on box 18 it shows that I made an extra 700.00 when that wasn't the case.

So to recap: Box 18-20 - 700.00| 0.00| 7701.

Box 18-20 - 2405| 48.10|Lakemore.

I don't understand what this means. Could it be an error?